# Using a text CSV field in an IN query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a TEXT column that holds an ids CSV, sort of like this

```
id    csvTextField  
2     38498734,2987349,5018,493850,12
```

I'm trying to use the contents of that field in a `user_id IN (CSV)` query.
I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.user_id IN (SELECT csvTextField FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.id=2)
```

But this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Use [13.5. SQL Syntax for Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to get what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET(col, 'csv as string')` function to get the desired results.

***Example***:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl2 
 WHERE
  FIND_IN_SET( 
    tbl2.user_id,
   ( select csvTextField FROM tbl1 WHERE tbl1.id=2 )
  ) > 0;
```